# How to group multiple ROW as ARRAY

Tags: mysql, json, array, mysql-8.0

**This is my current Query:**

```
SELECT innings_no,
Player_Name,
sum(NoBalls)                                                    as NB
    FROM (
           SELECT A.innings_no,
                  A.bowler,
                  A.Runs_In_Over + ifnull(B.Extra_runs, 0) = 0 as Maiden,
                  A.Balls - ifnull(B.NoBalls, 0)               as Balls,
                  A.Runs_In_Over + ifnull(B.Extra_runs, 0)     as Runs,
                  ifnull(C.Wicket, 0)                          as Wickets,
                  Zero,
                  Four,
                  Six,
                  ifnull(Wides, 0)                             as Wides,
                  ifnull(NoBalls, 0)                           as Noballs
           FROM (SELECT over_id,
                        ABBB.innings_no,
                        ABBB.bowler,
                        count(ABBB.ball_id)                 as Balls,
                        Sum(ABB.Runs_Scored)               As 'Runs_In_Over',
                        SUM(if(ABB.runs_scored = 0, 1, 0)) as Zero,
                        SUM(if(ABB.runs_scored = 4, 1, 0)) as Four,
                        SUM(if(ABB.runs_scored = 6, 1, 0)) as Six
                 FROM `database`.ball_by_ball ABBB
                        INNER JOIN `database`.batsman_scored ABB
                                   using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
                 where match_id = 981018
                 GROUP BY over_id, innings_no, bowler
                ) as A
                  LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT BBBB.over_id,
                        BBBB.innings_no,
                        BBBB.bowler,
                        SUM(if(BER.extra_type_id = 2, 1, 0)) as Wides,
                        SUM(if(BER.extra_type_id = 4, 1, 0)) as NoBalls,
                        Sum(BER.Extra_Runs)                  As 'Extra_runs'
                 FROM `database`.ball_by_ball BBBB
                        INNER JOIN `database`.extra_runs BER
                                   using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
                 WHERE match_id = 981018
                   and BER.Extra_Type_Id IN (2, 4)
                 GROUP BY over_id, innings_no, bowler
                ) as B
                using (over_id, innings_no, bowler)
                  LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT over_id,
                        CBBB.innings_no,
                        CBBB.bowler,
                        count(CBBB.bowler) as Wicket
                 FROM `database`.ball_by_ball CBBB
                        INNER JOIN `database`.wicket_taken CWT
                                   using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
                 WHERE match_id = 981018
                   and CWT.kind_out in (1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8)
                 GROUP BY over_id, innings_no, bowler
                ) as C
                using (over_id, innings_no, bowler)
           order by innings_no, over_id
           limit 1000
         ) AS DATA
           INNER JOIN `database`.Player C
                      ON DATA.bowler = C.Player_Id
    GROUP BY innings_no, Player_Name;
```

**This is Output:**

```
+------------+---------------+------+
| innings_no | Player_Name   | NB   |
+------------+---------------+------+
|          1 | S Aravind     |    0 |
|          1 | Iqbal Abdulla |    0 |
|          1 | SR Watson     |    0 |
|          1 | CJ Jordan     |    0 |
|          1 | YS Chahal     |    0 |
|          1 | STR Binny     |    0 |
|          2 | P Kumar       |    0 |
|          2 | DS Kulkarni   |    0 |
|          2 | RA Jadeja     |    0 |
|          2 | SB Jakati     |    1 |
|          2 | DJ Bravo      |    0 |
|          2 | DR Smith      |    0 |
+------------+---------------+------+
```

**I want to get output as below:**

```
+------------+--------------------------------+------------+
| innings_no |           Player_Name          |     NB     |
+------------+--------------------------------+------------+
|          1 | ["S Aravind", .. ,"STR Binny"] | [0, .. ,0] |
|          2 | ["P Kumar", .. ,"DR Smith"]    | [0, .. ,0] |
+------------+--------------------------------+------------+
```

In the above output, I want to group my result by `innings_no` and convert those two rows to an array. I tried `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function  on `Player_Name`
 but the output is not what I want, also it does not work on `sum(NoBalls)`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (`your query text except last semicolon`)
SELECT innings_no,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(Player_Name) Player_Names,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(NB) NBs
FROM cte
GROUP BY innings_no;
```

If You need a strict position according Player_Name and NB, use

```sql
WITH cte AS (`your query text except last semicolon`)
SELECT DISTINCT innings_no,
                JSON_ARRAYAGG(Player_Name) OVER win Player_Names,
                JSON_ARRAYAGG(NB) OVER win NBs
FROM cte
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY innings_no ORDER BY Player_Name);
```

Comment: i can do that by make my Query as a sub query. so can you please tell me is there any performance issues over using CTE?

Comment: I think no difference between CTE and subquery, because only one copy of CTE table is used. To be sure you can compare execution plans. And I recommend you to use CTEs instead of subqueries (and in your query too) - the query text will be more readable and clear.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge on database. execution plan means `EXPLAIN`? there both result is same. well in future i will use CTE, but with this problem, is there no easy way to solve this without using CTE or subqueries

Comment: @Rhidoy *execution plan means EXPLAIN?* Yes. *there both result is same* I expected just such a result.

Comment: well in future i will use CTE, but with this problem, is there no easy way to solve this without using CTE or subqueries. or this is the efficient solution?

Comment: @Rhidoy You need 2 grouping levels - by (innings_no, Player_Name) for to obtain separate names, and by (innings_no) for to obtain final result. A query may contain one grouping level only - so CTE or subquery is compulsory.

Comment: well, i will use your solution and i need second one but second one is not working, data is not grouping by `innings_no` and also order is not maintaining.

Comment: @Rhidoy Check [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bdb54b1a23dbd3d9fae88c20b8886f1). 1st variant works correctly. 2nd needs version 8.0.14 whereas online fiddles known to me provide 8.0.13 or lower.

Comment: yeah second one work without `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` only `innings_no` otherwise each unique `innings_no`,`player_name` is a unique entry.

To get the aggregate player_names:

```
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', player_name, '"'), ']') as Player_Names
```

And NBs

```
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(NoBalls), ']') as NBs
```

Comment: `CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', player_name, '"'), ']')) as Player_Names` gives the same output as `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` `group by innings_no`.
Output is below:
`["STR Binny"],"CJ Jordan"],"Iqbal Abdulla"],"CJ Jordan"],"S Aravind"],"CJ Jordan"],"S Aravind"],"SR Watson"],"CJ Jordan"],"YS Chahal"],"YS Chahal"],"YS Chahal"],"SR Watson"],"SR Watson"],"SR Watson"],"Iqbal Abdulla"],"YS Chahal"],"S Aravind"],"Iqbal Abdulla"],"Iqbal Abdulla"]`